# Send Email with Options step failing in Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, email, flow

I created a workflow in Microsoft Flow that is triggered when a new item is added to a SharePoint list.
This flow includes a "Send Email with Options" step that keeps failing with the following error:

> BadRequest. The request failed. Response content:
>   '{"status":400,"message":"No input parameters provided. Please provide
>   required input parameters 'To', 'Subject', 'Body' and
>   'Options'.\r\nclientRequestId:
>   b18047ba-5368-4e78-981b-b7025c027e81","source":"office365-cus.azconn-cus.p.azurewebsites.net"}'.

This is what that step looks like in the editor:

[image]

It only indicates the "To" field as being required.  That dynamic content is `triggerBody()['Approving_x0020_Manager']['Email']`, which I know works because it is the same as in a prior step that succeeds.  "Approving Manager" is a people-picker field in the form that a user fills out when adding a new item.

Also I have a prior step that sends an email (just the normal Send Email type) and that worked, so it must just have something to do with the specific "Send Email with Options"?  I don't understand why this step is failing as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you are referring to [this blog](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/multiple-attachments-single-email/) to send  multiple attachments on a single email using flow.

You can check the Vytenis's comment in [this blog](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/multiple-attachments-single-email/). To fix this is instead of appending "Attachment Content" (or in my case "File Content") to the "ContentBytes" property of the array, you need to append the following expression: body('Get_attachment_content').$content.

[image]

Refer to this thread:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Flow-and-SharePoint-Send-Email-with-Attachment-unreadable/td-p/129955

Comment: Wow....thank you for that, @JoannaW_MSFT!  I can't believe how difficult Flow is to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:**

Yes,Error message is irrelevant and does not help to fix the issue.
I have done the changes mentioned above and issue is fixed.

Please use below expression to get the file content:

```
body('Get_attachment_content').$content
```

[image]